# XML2JS conversion in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml2js

Hi I need one help When I am using xml2js node js lib. I am able to convert the  XML to JSON object however when I am iterating JSON element I can see the  '$': as few of the key elements.
Is there a way I can eliminate the $ key ?

Comment: Those are the attributes of a node. What do you mean by "eliminate" exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try regex to replace the $ key

or

use JSON.parse() to replace the $.

Comment: Hi JSON.parse is not working it doesn't replace the $

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attrkey` to change the `$` key to sth else.

Or you can ignore it (do not create attribute node) with `ignoreAttrs` set to `true`

as per the [readme of xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)